# Spring Hibernate, stack overflow when trying to get entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I get:

> java.lang.StackOverflowError  at
>   kamienica.dao.ApartmentDaoImpl.findById(ApartmentDaoImpl.java:52)     at
>   kamienica.dao.ApartmentDaoImpl.findById(ApartmentDaoImpl.java:52)     at
>   kamienica.dao.ApartmentDaoImpl.findById(ApartmentDaoImpl.java:52)
>        (and so on..)

When trying to get an object by it's primary key.

Here is AbstractDAO:

```
public abstract class AbstractDao<PK extends Serializable, T> {

    private final Class<T> persistentClass;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public AbstractDao() {
        this.persistentClass = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) this.getClass().getGenericSuperclass())
                .getActualTypeArguments()[1];
    }

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    protected SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    protected Session getSession() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public T findByPK(PK id) {
        Session session = getSession();
        T out = (T) session.load(persistentClass, id);
        session.close();
        return out;
    }
```

And here is the ApartmentDAO implementation:

```
@Repository("apatmentDao")
public class ApartmentDaoImpl extends AbstractDao<Integer, Apartment> implements ApartmentDao {

    public void save(Apartment apatment) {
        persist(apatment);

    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Apartment> getList() {
        Criteria criteria = createEntityCriteria();
        criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("apartmentNumber"));
        return (List<Apartment>) criteria.list();
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteByID(int id) {
        Query query = getSession().createSQLQuery("delete from Apartment where id = :id");
        query.setInteger("id", id);
        query.executeUpdate();
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Apartment apatment) {
        update(apatment);
    }


        @Override
        public Apartment findById(int id) {
// If I put System.out.println(id) here it will print id 
// number until the stack overflow
            Apartment ap = findById(id);
            return ap;
        }
```

I have no idea what is causing this problem. Other methods are working just fine...

Comment: Problems seems to be that you call `Apartment.findById(int id)` indefinitely. You should call `super.findById(id)`.

Answer (score 1):

You're recursively calling the `findById` method.

```
     @Override
        public Apartment findById(int id) {
            // Here you're recursively calling findById
            Apartment ap = findById(id);
            return ap;
        }
```

You could do something like this I suppose,

```
        @Override
        public Apartment findById(int id) {
            return findByPK(new Integer(id));
        }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: `AbstractDao` has  such method `findByPK(id)`

Comment: I have changed  
'return (T) getSession().get(persistentClass, new Integer((int) id));'
And that did the trick. Huge thanks!!